# Generating a new ID based on max-value in database

Tags: mysql, database

I'm trying to get my program to generate new identifications based on the highest ID-number already within the database.

```
    Dim kobling As New Tilkobling
    Dim hentOrdreNummer As String = "SELECT MAX(ordreID) FROM bestilling"
    Dim svar As DataTable
    bOrdreID = hentOrdreNummer + 1

    kobling.sporring(user, password, hentOrdreNummer)
    svar = kobling.hentData()
```

All this returns is, ofcause, the sql-command (with the +1 it crashes due to string/integer i assume). Is there a simple way to do this?

**New Code:**

```
Dim kobling As New Tilkobling
        Dim hentOrdreNummer As String = "SELECT * FROM bestilling"
        Dim svar As DataTable
        kobling.sporring(user, password, hentOrdreNummer)
        svar = kobling.hentData()
        Dim temprad As DataRow
        Dim nyID, modID As String
        For Each temprad In svar.Rows
            nyID = temprad("ordreID")
            modID = nyID + 1
            bOrdreID = modID
```

This works, tho, It starts with the lowest number, and I get a error message untill it reach a number thats not already taken.

**Working Code:**

```
 Dim kobling As New Tilkobling
        Dim hentOrdreNummer As String = "SELECT MAX(ordreID) AS ordreID FROM bestilling"
        Dim svar As DataTable
        kobling.sporring(user, password, hentOrdreNummer)
        svar = kobling.hentData()
        Dim temprad As DataRow
        Dim nyID, modID As String
        For Each temprad In svar.Rows
            nyID = temprad("ordreID")
            modID = nyID + 1
            bOrdreID = modID
```

Comment: Your going to need to actually run that SQL against your database and return a result and then add + 1 to the result. Alternatively you could do it within the SQL so "SELECT MAX(orderID) + 1 From Bestilling"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT IFNULL(MAX(ordreID),0)+1 FROM bestilling
```

It will return the new possible ID i.e., max(id)+1.

Comment: This does the same for me, insert "SELECT" from the SQL-line as new ID :S

Comment: @Freshman: Are you able to debug the code and see what the variable holds?

Comment: The variable contain the SQL string.

Comment: @Freshman: You should first execute this query, store the result into a variable and then use the variable while inserting new record.

Comment: Think I'm getting closer, tho, it's unable to target the highest number within the database before trying to insert a new row

Comment: Figured it out, couldn't without your pointers, thank you :)!

Answer (score 0):

You need to establish a connection to a database and actually run your SQL against it.
You then create a variable to store your result in and + 1 to your result.
You can not simply declare a string of "SELECT . . . . " and then expect to add + 1 to it.